# Measuring potential

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-fields, potential

I apologize if the question below has been asked -- I could not find an answer.

A charged conductor some distance above ground generates an electric field and corresponding potential profile.

How can I measure the potential difference between two points?
Say I place two metal probes, discharged and small enough so as not to disturb the field.
Since the net charge in each conductor is zero, how can one in practice measure the potential at those probe points?
What happens if I connect a large impedance between the two probes.
I'm now learning about these things and my intuition fails me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to have probe wires in order to bring any charge into the voltmeter so it can be measured. Electrons will flow in a wire because they are attracted or repelled by other nearby charges. For example, if the charge is positive and you place the probe near the charge, electrons in the probe wire will move toward the charge, causing the other end of the wire (which is connected to the voltmeter) to be proportionally depleted of electrons (assuming no other force is on the electrons in the probe wire--which is hard to accomplish). The same happens on the other probe wire. So that way the voltmeter gets to 'see' the potentials at the probe point. But note that practically speaking you will need special probes and voltmeter specifically for this. Typically that means a small device that really just measures field gradient rather than potential at two points.

So the bottom line is that measuring potentials is accomplished in practice by measuring gradient across the region between the two points, and then multiply the distance time the gradient to get potential difference.

Comment: Interesting. It makes sense but I have a follow-up question. Since the probe and probe wire are nearly ideal conductors, wouldn't your explanation suggest that there is a lateral electric field in the wire itself? The voltmeter then must be providing a sort of leakage path... Thanks.